# PHP Session vars inside of a class

Tags: php

I have the a user object class that I have the following function in. The function works and it lets a user login and everything just fine. But when I try to create a session variable within the function it doesn't seem to work. I create the session variable in the function, and then in the calling page that calls the function I do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` and it's blank. Is it not possible to create session variables inside of a class?

```
 public function userLogin() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password AND status = :status LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", $this->password , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "status", "active" , PDO::PARAM_STR );            
        $stmt->execute();

        $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if( $valid ) {
            $success = true;
                session_start();
                // Set user session variables
                foreach($stmt as $row) {

                    $_SESSION["username"] = $row['username'];
                    $_SESSION["role"]     = $row['role']; 
                }

        }

        $con = null;
        return $success;
     }catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         return $success;
     }
 }
```

Comment: are you sure you're calling session_start()?

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` in your code?

Comment: No `session_start()` call, no automatic loading/saving of $_SESSION. Until you make that magical `session_start()` call, $_SESSION is just a plain empty array that happens to be a superglobal. All of the persistence/auto-loading/auto-saving is triggered by session_start().

Comment: I just added the session_start() and it still comes out empty

Comment: even with the session_start() it doesn't work, do i need to add that as well in the calling page or only where i set the session vars?

Comment: @BradHazelnut - yes session_start() needs to be in every page you set or get sessions...

Comment: I just added it on the calling page and now it gives me an error saying Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var/www/test/index.php on line 64 array(0) { }

Comment: I figured out what the problem is, but i can't seem to figure out how to get the actual query results, this is the first time im using pdo so please forgive the ignorance. The issue is foreach($stmt as $row) only shows the the following when i do var_dump "object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(83) "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1" }"

Comment: how do i get the query results?

Comment: I don't know how to accomplish this, but if i do the following it doesn't work $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();            $result yields 0 results. but i do $valid = $stmt->fetchAll(); Then it gives me the correct results, is it not possible to have "fetchColumn" and "fetchAll" off the statment

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` is a **superglobal** variable and accessible everywhere.

You need to use `session_start()` before settings sessions if you are not doing so already.

Also check the two conditions you have to see if it is getting inside those scopes:

```
if( $valid ) {

foreach($stmt as $row) {
```

Comment: proper terminology. $_session is a "superglobal". "global" in PHP terms is a variable that exists at the top of the scope tree, but isn't visible anywhere else except at that top level scope (unless you `global $var` within another scope). "superglobals" implicitly exist in all scopes.

Comment: @MarcB - forgive me, sensei...I will not repeat it.